# Is this a correct scenario to use WebSocket?

Tags: performance, concurrency, websocket

I have a browser plugin which will be installed on 40,000 dekstops.
This plugin will connect to a backend configuration file available via https, e.g. http://somesite/config_file.js.

The plugin is configured to poll this backend resource once/day.
But there is only one backend server. So if 40,000 endpoints start polling together the server might crash.
I could think of randomize the polling frenquency from the desktop plugins. But randomization still does not gurantee that there will not be a overload at the server.

Is using websocket in this scenario solves the scalability issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling once a day is very little.

I don't see any upside for Websockets unless you switch to Push and have more notifications.

However, staggering the polling does make a lot of sense, since syncing requests for the same time is like writing a DoS attack against your own server.

Staggering doesn't necessarily have to be random and IMHO, it probably shouldn't.

You could start with a fixed time and add a second per client ID, allowing for ~86K connections in 24 hours which should be easy for any server to handle.

As a side note, 40K concurrent connections might not as hard to achieve as you imagine.

---

**EDIT** (relating to the comments)

1. Websockets vs. Server Sent Events:

   IMHO, when pushing data (vs. polling), I would prefer Websockets over Server Sent Events (SSE).

   Websockets have a few advantages, such as client side communication which allows clients to `ping` the server and confirm that the connection is still alive.
2. The Specific Use-Case:

   From the description in the question and the comments it seems that you're using browser clients with a custom plugin and that the updates you wish to install daily might require the browser to be active.

   This raises different questions that effect the implementation (are the client browsers open all day? do you have any control over the client browsers and their environment? can you guarantee installation while the browser is closed?).

   ...

   IMHO, you might consider having the client plugins test for an update each morning as they load for the first time during that day (first access).

   People arrive at work in different times and they open their browsers for the first time at different schedules. So the 40K requests you're expecting will be naturally scattered across that timeline (probably a 20-30 minute timespan).

   This approach makes sure that the browsers and computers are actually open (making the update possible) and that the update requests are staggered over a period of time (about 33.3 requests per second, if my assumption is correct).

   If you're serving a pre-written static configuration file (perhaps updated by the server daily), avoiding dynamic content and minimizing any database calls, than 33 req/sec should be very easy to manage.

Comment: Thanks for some interesting points.. I guess websocket is not suitable for this scenario. Possibly a server-side event might be a better alternate approach - which can push updates to the client.

Comment: IMHO, SSE are a poor alternative to websockets. If you're implementing push, definitely use websockets. But for an update that arrives once a day and isn't urgent, push seems like an overkill. A cronjob is by far easier to implement, as long as update requests are spread evenly on an allotted update period so the server isn't stressed.

Comment: It's little more complicated than that. Since the plugins will be installed on local browsers, there is no control on these plugins after these are installed. How do you suggest to implement using a cronjob? maybe I am not getting the point.I guess, I will try to get a unique hash value from each computer's ip address and use that to calculate the unique polling time from each plugin. It has its downside (not all users getting the update immediately), but definitely I cannot have all the plugins hitting the server at the same time.

Comment: @ShibasisSengupta I updated my answer to reflect the discussion as well as suggest another approach that might fit.

Comment: Thanks @Myst...appreciate your help